# Why can't I insert cursor.fetchall() into a text widget?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to insert text into a text widget from tkinter. When i put `cursor.fetchall()` into the argument I get the error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Users\lmaor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 1705, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\lmaor\Desktop\Database\ComputerShop Database.py", line 54,
>   in showCustomers
>       txtTerminal.insert(END, " " + cursor.fetchall() + "\n") TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

I have tried using `cursor.fetchall()` without the "\n" so there is no string attached, but it just shows up as nothing.

`txtTerminal` is a tkinter text widget
`showCustomers()` is activated with a button called btnShowCustomers

## This function is supposed to print the full list of all customers in the table

```
def showCustomers():
    print(" ")
    print("Customers:")
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tblCustomers")
    print(cursor.fetchall())
    txtTerminal.config(state = NORMAL)
    txtTerminal.insert(END, " " + cursor.fetchall() + "\n")
    txtTerminal.config(state = DISABLED)
```

When the results are printed in the 'Python 3.7.2 Shell' it shows as

> 'Customers: [(1, 'John', 'Smith')]'

This is what I want the text inside txtTerminal to look like, instead I get either an error or nothing.

Comment: Either use `" "+str(cursor.fetchall())+"\n"` or `f" {cursor.fetchall()}\n"`.  BTW, calling `cursor.fetchall()` twice is not correct as the last call will get empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the result is a tuple inside of list(Basically its a two dimensional set),it will not insert whole tuple values in text widget.

Try this out:

```
def showCustomers():
     print(" ")
     print("Customers:")
     cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tblCustomers")
     print(cursor.fetchall())
     txtTerminal.config(state = NORMAL)
     for line in cursor.fetchall():
         for data in line:
              txtTerminal.insert(END, " " + data + "\n")
     txtTerminal.config(state = DISABLED)
```

The main thing i changed is the insert mechanism i.e

```
for line in cursor.fetchall():
         for data in line:
              txtTerminal.insert(END, " " + data + "\n")
```

It will take the first tuple out of the list as 'line' and then a value will be taken as 'data' from the 'line'.
Atlast, it will insert that data into the text widget.

Feel free to ask question or if error comes.

Till then,Ciao!